# Put `stdout` in an `NSTextView` while running the a command

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, command-line, stdout

I'm creating a Cocoa Application, which will need to run the `rails` command. This command generates an output, and streams it to `stdout`. I want to show this output to the user in an `NSTextView` (so basicly stream the `stdout` to the `NSTextView`). My application should not 'hang' when the command is running (e.g. the `git` command takes a long time to finish uploading). I don't really care about how I should run the command, as long as I can set the working directory.

Using a Ruby framework for Cocoa is no option, as I also need to do this for non-ruby commands like `git`.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

```
NSTask       * task;
NSPipe       * pipe;
NSFileHandle * fileHandle;

task       = [ [ NSTask alloc ] init ];
pipe       = [ NSPipe pipe ];
fileHandle = [ pipe fileHandleForReading ];

[ fileHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify ];
[ task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ls" ];
[ task setStandardOutput: pipe ];
[ task setStandardError: pipe ];
[ task launch ];
```

You can then use the file handle to get stdout.
The working directory can be set with the **setCurrentDirectoryPath** method.
Arguments can be set with the **setArguments** method.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use the data during it es read use the approach with `NSNotification` which is described in [this post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/23865-nstask-output-to-nstextview-more-questions.html) on cocoabuilder.com.

Basically this sets up an `NSPipe` object, connects the stdout of the `NSTask` to the pipe and listens for `NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification` of the pipe to process the data which was pushed to the pipe.